# Android: How to release an onClick event handler for all the elements of an UI

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, event-handling

I do have multiple buttons in a View:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Überspringen"/>
```

I do want to trigger an onClick Event if any of this buttons is clicked, so called View-wide onClick Event Handler wrapping.

**What i tried:** In order to release an onClick event, it is needed to add an onclick - event to each button, than to put the onClick Event in the controller etc.

**Issue:** I can have up to 7-17 etc buttons, those don't want to have too many onclick event functions.

**Question:** How to add an onClick Event handler for everysingle element/button of an UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create function like this:

```
    private void applyClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener, View view) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                applyClickListener(listener, ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof Button) {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
```

...and then use it like this:

```
        applyClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("zzz", "click just happened");
            }
        }, findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView());
```

However I reserve right to mention your task sounds pretty weird.

Comment: First of, Thank You for your Answer and Contribution! Well the thing is... in order to create a new View, multiple UI componentents of different View files with the help of `include` will be integrated into the new View. Everysingle `include` view can have buttons, by clicking which, the data will be saved to a DB. Which pretty much implies, there at best there should be only one eventhandler function with the very same components, instead of repeating the very same eventhandler function for each possible `button` of every view included.

Comment: Also an additional question: is there some sort of container for multiple buttons, by clicking one button it generates an `Event`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good practice, but i would do it this way:

Create your method in the .java file.

```
    public void myMethod(View view) {

}
```

Go to your XML layout file and find your buttons. Then add the following attribute to your buttons in your XML code.

```
android:onClick="myMethod"
```

Or you can just simply find this attribute in attributes panel in graphic designer.